# check if numbers in a column are ascending by a certain value (R dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a column of numbers (index) in a dataframe like the below. I am attempting to check if these numbers are in ascending order by the value of 1. For example, group B and C do not ascend by 1. While I can check by sight, my dataframe is thousands of rows long, so I'd prefer to automate this. Does anyone have advice? Thank you!

```
group index

A     0
A     1
A     2
A     3
A     4
B     0
B     1
B     2
B     2
C     0
C     3
C     1
C     2
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works. `diff` calculates the difference between the two subsequent numbers, and then we can use `all` to see if all the differences are 1. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(Result = all(diff(index) == 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   group Result
#   <chr> <lgl> 
# 1 A     TRUE  
# 2 B     FALSE 
# 3 C     FALSE
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "group index
A 0
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 0
B 1
B 2
B 2
C 0
C 3
C 1
C 2",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `aggregate` could help

```
> aggregate(.~group,df1,function(v) all(diff(v)==1))
  group index
1     A  TRUE
2     B FALSE
3     C FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by group, get the difference between the current and previous value (`shift`) and check if `all` the differences are equal to 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Result = all((index - shift(index))[-1] == 1)), group]
#   group Result
#1:     A   TRUE
#2:     B  FALSE
#3:     C  FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), index = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```